# How to show a picture connected to select tag and with a button on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good evening. I am still learning the basics of HTML, JS, JSON, CSS etcetera.

I am just messing around and decided to make something like a PokeDex;
If you click a Pokemon from the select section, I want that the picture of that Pokemon will show in a div, but I've no idea how. Here's my code;

```
    <div id="div1">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Show Pokemon</button>
        <select id="numbers">
              <option value="0">Bulbasaur</option>
              <option value="1">Ivysaur</option>
              <option value="2">Venusaur</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="picture"></div>

    <script>
      function myFunction(){
         ???
     }
    </script>
```

So if I click Bulbasaur, and then click the button, I want "bulbasaur.jpg"  in my picture div etc etc..

Anyone know how? I am very close but I just don't know how.

Comment: do you think `???` is close ?

Comment: Hint.  Use `img` tag with `src` attribute

Comment: No, ??? is not close, but I didn't showed what I tried. Something like if(document.getElementById("numbers").value = 1 { document.getElemenyById("picture").??? = ???

Answer (score 0):

Maybe having a style with each background image and changing the class of the div when your button is clicked.

```
<script>
   function myFunction(){
      if($("input[name=numbers]:checked").val() == '0')
        {
           document.getElementById("picture").className = "imgBulbasaur";
        }
   }
</script>


<style type="text/css">
  .imgBulbasaur{
      background-image: url('../images/Bulbasaur.png');
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's not working for me atm and I don't really understand the code to be fair. I thought something like this: if(document.getElementById("numbers").value = 1 { document.getElemenyById("picture").??? = ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("picture").style.backgroundImage` to select the background image

```css
#picture{
  height:100px;
  display:block;
  background-color:black;
  background-size:100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
 <div id="div1">
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Show Pokemon</button>
        <select id="numbers">
              <option value="0">Bulbasaur</option>
              <option value="1">Ivysaur</option>
              <option value="2">Venusaur</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="picture"></div>

    <script>
      var arr=['https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=ff0000&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373','https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=00ff00&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373','https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=77&bg=0000ff&txtclr=ffffff&txt=1230x373&w=1230&h=373'];
      function myFunction(){
        var inx=document.getElementById("numbers").selectedIndex; document.getElementById("picture").style.backgroundImage='url(\''+arr[inx]+'\')';
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a JSON object and set an array of pictures that you want to use for your pokemon. Then I would set a listener to follow the mouse click. Then add method to the object that would switch the photo to the correct img from the array. That way you could structure it in such a way to deal with each case, instead of building a listener for each pokemon.

Actually, 3 JSON objects would likely be better. One for data storage and modification, one for event handling, and one for front end modification. You can see a vanilla js, implementation of something similar in my [github](http://www.github.com/dwmorrisdev/vanillaTodos).

Comment: I actually have json behind it. This is what I have there: [
{
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "type": "Grass",
    "getable": "Gift from Prof. Oak"
},
    
{
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "type": "Grass/Poison",
    "getable": "Evolueer Bulbasaur"
},
    
{
    "name": "Venusaur",
    "type": "Grass/Poison",
    "getable": "Evolueer Bulbasaur"
} Can I add pictures somehow?